# C - Accessing variables in a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, reference

I have a struct `Item` with a variable `value1`, and I placed an instance of this struct in a queue. I would now like to peek into the queue and obtain the data held in the struct instance.

The below code works as expected.

```
Item *itemHead = queue_peek_head(itemQueue);
printf("Head: %d\n", itemHead->value1);
```

However, I would like to do the same thing preferably without additional variables like `itemHead`. Is there any way to do this? My original line of thinking led me to the below code which, as I figured, doesn't work (dereferencing `void *` pointer, invalid `void` expression).

```
*(queue_peek_head(itemQueue))->value1; //doesn't give me value1
```

Can anyone come up with a (preferably one line) way of accessing `value1` from the first `Item` in the queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`((Item*)queue_peek_head(itemQueue))->value1`

The compiler needs to know the type in order to access the member of the structure.

(Also, you wouldn't do `*(somePointer)->` unless there's a pointer to a pointer, there's two dereferences there.)

Comment: Thank you! I'm still grasping pointers and such, so I really appreciate your help.